# How can get the table that is the container of a cell to which I have a reference? (Applescript-Numbers-Mac)

Tags: applescript, applescript-numbers

I use `a reference to cell...` in order to later set the value of the cell without having to go through the `document:sheet:table` "path". 
I need the name of the table of this cell in another part of the code, but I can't get it directly from the cell (the reference to the cell). Tables have the property `parent` but cells don't :-(.

I found something similar here [properties-of-an-object-or-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240039/applescript-getting-a-list-of-all-properties-of-an-object-or-class) but doesn't help.

The only way I found is to store the information of the table in another variable.

Any ideas to improve it?

Here is some code that works:

```
tell application "Numbers"
tell document 1
    tell sheet 1
        tell table 1
            (*
            more code here
            I make sure the selection range is a cell
            etc.
            *)
            set cellXref to a reference to cell (name of selection range)
            set cellXrefTable to it
            set tableXName to name of cellXrefTable --or set tableXName to name of it
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
set value of cellXref to 1000000
end tell
```

Comment: While asking consider using a general tag for a technology you are reffering to among with more specified tags.

Comment: @itwasntme Thanks. Done.

Comment: I would just have `set tableXName to name of it` after the cellXref line and use that.