# Finding file type without using info for command? (macOS-AppleScript)

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to walk through several servers with thousands of files each and log some information about them.

I had it set to ignore alias, or so I thought. If I use the "info for" command to identify the file and it's a broken alias it will pop up an "There was a problem connecting to the server 'X.X.X.X'" message. This wouldn't be too much of a problem, except it doesn't seem to recognize this as an ACTUAL error. It just sits there with the window open waiting for me to click "OK" before it will move on.

Anyone have an ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240039/applescript-getting-a-list-of-all-properties-of-an-object-or-class/74831845#74831845

Answer (score 0):

Most of the properties of `info for` are also available in `System Events`.

If you've got a string path `Macintosh HD:Users:MyUser:Desktop:something.ext` named `thePath` then both

```
set fileType to file type of (info for alias thePath)
```

and

```
tell application "System Events"
    set fileType to file type of disk item thePath
end tell
```

return the same information.